# Issue with Integrating resteasy with Spring

Tags: java, spring, jboss7.x, resteasy

I am trying to integrate my resteasy application with spring. Below is my pom dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.GA</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>sjsxp</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

But when I build and start my application on Jboss 7.x I am getting the below exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.InjectorFactory.createPropertyInjector(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/jboss/resteasy/spi/PropertyInjector;
```

Any idea how to resolve the issue?

Comment: may it be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334427/resteasy-3-integration-with-spring-3-not-working ?

Answer (score 0):

If the resteasy version of your project was higher than 2.3.5 that is default version that comes with JBoss 7.x, you need to exclude module of JBoss using jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
...<exclusions>  
 <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" />
</exclusions>...
```

Following you need provide the resteasy jars in your project.

This solved this problem to me.

Hope that helps